# At most one relations: using Negation Vs Implication

Tags: predicate-logic, quantification

I am trying to come to terms with expressing using quantifiers using various examples.

My question here is about a general approach for expressing **at-most one** relations in logical language.

For example, given the statement M(x,y) = "Person x *is* married to Person y".

Now the way I usually find  some translations for the follow-up statement *"A person can only be married to one another person at a time"* is like this:

¬(∃x∃y∃z.(M(x,y) ∧ M(x,z) ∧ x≠y ∧ x≠z ∧ y≠z))

whereas, **I** often think of them as a statement involving implication

<strike>∃x∃y∃z.(M(x,y) ∧ M(x,z) => x≠y ∧ x≠z ∧ y=z)</strike>.

∀x∀y∀z.(M(x,y) ∧ M(x,z) => x≠y ∧ x≠z ∧ y=z)

Are both of the above approaches - one using the negation and the other using the implication same and equally valid?

Comment: The first difference is that the first formula exclude self-marriage...

Comment: thanks, corrected

Comment: For the second formula, the quantifiers must be universal ones, because you are expressing a sort of "rule": if a person whatever has to "marriage partners", these two must be the same person.

Comment: If so, you are right: you can equivalently write it as: **¬∃x∃y∃z(M(x,y) ∧ M(x,z) ∧ y≠z)**

Comment: understood, but will that be the same as using universal q. ∀x∀y∀z.(M(x,y) ∧ M(x,z) => x≠y ∧ x≠z ∧ y=z)? My question is that, does negating the existence is the same as asserting the existence of a universal rule?

Comment: We have to exploit two equivalence: that of **¬∃x¬** and **∀x** and that regarding **¬(P ⇒ Q)** and **(P & ¬Q)**

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA at-most relation is stated by enumerating variables and then using AND. But could you please hint how to scale it to "at-most n"? For ex. in a polygamous society, how the statement could be adapted to state "at-most n persons"

Comment: In both formulas, x≠y ∧ x≠z is not part of the phrase you are translating: "A person can only be married to one another person at a time". With those additions, it is a somewhat awkward way to translate, "A person cannot be married to himself and also cannot be married to two distinct people". A better translation of that sentence would be ∀x∀y.M(x,y) => (x≠y ∧ ∀z.M(x,z) =>y=z).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second sentence is correct, but the first is not. Adjusting the formulation a little, your first sentence is:

¬(∃x)(∃y)(∃z)(Mxy ∧ Mxz ∧ x≠y ∧ x≠z ∧ y≠z)

This would be consistent with a person being married to two distinct people, provided neither is the person themselves. Instead you need:

¬(∃x)(∃y)(∃z)(Mxy ∧ Mxz ∧ (x=y ∨ x=z ∨ y≠z))

This is logically equivalent to your second sentence:

(∀x)(∀y)(∀z)((Mxy ∧ Mxz) => (x≠y ∧ x≠z ∧ y=z))

where => is the material conditional.

To explain how to extend this formula to "at most n" as you ask in the comments, it would simplify things if we remove the self-marriage exclusion to a separate sentence and simply write:

(∀x)(¬Mxx)

We can now express at most one as:

(∀x)(∀y)(∀z)((Mxy ∧ Mxz) =>  y=z)

And at most two as:

(∀x)(∀y)(∀z)(∀w)((Mxy ∧ Mxz ∧ Mxw) =>  (y=z ∨ y=w ∨ z=w))

We can then extend to any finite number just by adding another variable and specifying that if x has more than the regulation marriage partners, then some pair of them is identical.

Comment: please note that your statement ¬(∃x)(∃y)(∃z)(Mxy ∧ Mxz ∧ (x=y ∨ x=z ∨ y≠z)) is different from my statement ¬(∃x∃y∃z.(M(x,y) ∧ M(x,z) ∧ x≠y ∧ x≠z ∧ y≠z)). I meant to negate the entire statement "there is an x and y and z s.t. x is married to y and x is married to z and....). But are you negating just (∃x)?

Comment: this answer helped to clarify a few points - but kindly expand: when I wrote at-most n, I did not mean n as a placeholder there. It was a question from a maths textbook:
"Problem 3.37. (a) Translate the following sentence into a predicate formula:
There is a student who has e-mailed at most n other people in the class,
besides possibly himself."

Comment: I am negating the entire statement. I am not sure what negating just (∃x) means. If a ¬ appears at the beginning of a sentence, it is negating that sentence.

Comment: got it. Is it possible to express a generic quantifier in FOL like being asked in question 3.37? It's not possible as such directly, but may be there is a clever workaround? Well, the restriction is that you can only use E(x,y) for x email y and = symbol

Comment: You could do it in second order logic. Or of course you could just introduce arithmetic or set theory. There is no way to do it in first order logic that I'm aware of.